# switch statement having only one case

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

I only have one case in switch statement

```
switch ($coreName) {
    case 'stock':
        $result['website'] = ($result['website']) ? $websiteStatus[$result['website']] : "";
    break;
}
```

My question is this a good practice or shall I use an if statement for this? Any performance differences or anything?

Comment: In this case it's just a convoluted way of writing an if statement, so you kind of answered your own question. Also, as long as you have doubts about the basics of programming, don't get caught up in the performance story because it will almost never matter.

Comment: If you expect to add other cases later, it's perfectly OK.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I'm sorry but that's not really good advice. I can "expect" a great many things about a project. If all these expectations are to be prepared in code, you risk designing and developing a spaceship to fry an egg. Your code should ALWAYS follow the proverbial JEEP principle (just enough essential parts) to make it work. When the requirements change, THEN is the time to swap out and/or expand. This is always important and especially for novices who need to learn best practices. Either you already have multiple cases that warrant a switch or you don't and you use an if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to [phpBench.com](http://www.phpbench.com/) and scroll down to see the results between `if` and `case`, you can see that using an `if` statement is slightly faster, but the results aren't too different. (Screenshot below)

[image]

You may as well use an `if` as it is easier to read, less code and is still faster (even by only a tiny amount).

```
if($corename === "stock") {
  $result['website'] = ($result['website']) ? $websiteStatus[$result['website']] : "";
}
```

`case` should only be used when you compare multiple values rather than just one. This is the same as using `elseif`. Using `if` is the most suited for this specifically.

Answer (score 2):

Use if else Only when :

```
1. you have only 2 or more conditions OR You have multiple conditions in single if else.
```

And  use switch when

```
1. You have to compare `ONE` variable value against multiple.
```

In your case if else is better

Comment: The first condition makes no sense to be honest. What if you have multiple boundaries?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing speaks against this from a technical point of view.

So the question to answer is: *why* did you implement a `switch` statement instead of an `if` conditional?

I'd say the default should be an "normal" `if` condition, unless special reasons point to a `switch` instead. The two primary reasons might be:

- extensibility (for later additions)
- readability (for other coders)

Especially the first case should be considered here. If it might become necessary to extend the handling, then certainly using a `switch` right away is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do a simple if, like this :

```
if($coreName == 'stock')
    {
        $result['website'] = ($result['website']) ? $websiteStatus[$result['website']] : "";
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes but are there any advantages if we use if over switch in this case.

Comment: Switch is for when you have to test multiple cases. In your specific case, it's not appropriate. In terms of performance, if ... else is pretty god (@BeatAlex's answer details it more than I can).